# Sliding window based on Akka actor source not behaving as expected

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

Using below code I'm attempting to use an actor as a source and send messages of type Double to be processed via a sliding window.

The sliding windows is defined as `sliding(2, 2)` to calculate each sequence of twp values sent.

Sending the message:

```
        actorRef.tell(10, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(30, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(40, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
```

Should calculate the average as follows :

```
10 + 20 / 2 = 15
30 + 40 / 2 = 35
```

But the calculation does not appear to be invoked in below code.

Here I output the value :

```
    movingAverage.runForeach(n -> {
        if( n > 0){
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }, system);
```

src code:

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.stream.CompletionStrategy;
import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;

import java.util.Optional;

public class FilterThreshold {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final akka.actor.ActorSystem system = akka.actor.ActorSystem.create("Source");

        final int bufferSize = 1;
        final Source<Double, ActorRef> source =
                Source.actorRef(
                        elem -> {
                            // complete stream immediately if we send it Done
                            if (elem == Done.done()) {
                                return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
                            } else {
                                return Optional.empty();
                            }
                        },
                        // never fail the stream because of a message
                        elem -> Optional.empty(),
                        bufferSize,
                        OverflowStrategy.dropHead());
        ActorRef actorRef = source.to(Sink.foreach(System.out::println)).run(system);

        actorRef.tell(10, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(30, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(40, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());

        Source<Double, ActorRef> movingAverage = source
                .sliding(2, 2)
                .map(window -> (window.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).sum()) / window.size());


        movingAverage.runForeach(n -> {
            if( n > 0){
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }, system);

    }
}
```

I've edited the code from https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/sliding.html

How to apply the sliding window function defined as `movingAverage` to calculate the values sent via the Akka actor `actorRef` ?

Update:

The method `permaterialize` takes an actor system as a parameter.

Updating the code from:

```
final Pair<ActorRef, Source<Double, ActorRef>> prematPair = source.preMaterialize();
```

to:

```
final Pair<ActorRef, Source<Double, ActorRef>> prematPair = source.preMaterialize(system);
```

results in a compile time error:

```
Required type:
Pair
<ActorRef,
Source<Double, ActorRef>>

Provided:
Pair
<ActorRef,
Source<Double, NotUsed>>
```

Is there an alternative method I should use ?

Updated code posted:

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.japi.Pair;
import akka.stream.CompletionStrategy;
import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;

import java.util.Optional;

public class FilterThreshold {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final akka.actor.ActorSystem system = akka.actor.ActorSystem.create("Source");

        final int bufferSize = 1;
        final Source<Double, ActorRef> source =
                Source.actorRef(
                        elem -> {
                            System.out.println("elem is "+elem);
                            // complete stream immediately if we send it Done
                            if (elem == Done.done()) {
                                return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
                            } else {
                                return Optional.empty();
                            }
                        },
                        // never fail the stream because of a message
                        elem -> Optional.empty(),
                        bufferSize,
                        OverflowStrategy.dropHead());

        // source is as before
        final Pair<ActorRef, Source<Double, ActorRef>> prematPair = source.preMaterialize(system);

        Flow<Double, Double, NotUsed> movingAverageFlow =
                Flow.of(Double.class)
                        .sliding(2, 2)
                        .map(window -> (window.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).sum()) / window.size());

        final Source<Double, ActorRef> prematSource = prematPair.second();

        prematSource.via(movingAverageFlow).runForeach(n -> {
            System.out.println("n is "+n);
            if (n > 0) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }, system);

        final ActorRef actorRef = prematPair.first();

        actorRef.tell(10, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());

    }
}
```

Update2 :

Using code :

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.japi.Pair;
import akka.stream.CompletionStrategy;
import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;

import java.util.Optional;

public class FilterThreshold {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final akka.actor.ActorSystem system = akka.actor.ActorSystem.create("Source");

        final int bufferSize = 1;
        final Source<Double, ActorRef> source =
                Source.actorRef(
                        elem -> {
                            System.out.println("elem is "+elem);
                            // complete stream immediately if we send it Done
                            if (elem == Done.done()) {
                                return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
                            } else {
                                return Optional.empty();
                            }
                        },
                        // never fail the stream because of a message
                        elem -> Optional.empty(),
                        bufferSize,
                        OverflowStrategy.dropHead());

        // source is as before
        final Pair<ActorRef, Source<Double, NotUsed>> prematPair = source.preMaterialize(system);
        final ActorRef actorRef = prematPair.first();
        final Source<Double, NotUsed> prematSource = prematPair.second();

        Flow<Double, Double, NotUsed> movingAverageFlow =
                Flow.of(Double.class)
                        .sliding(2, 2)
                        .map(window -> (window.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).sum()) / window.size());

        prematSource.via(movingAverageFlow).runForeach(n -> {
            System.out.println("n is "+n);
            if (n > 0) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }, system);

        actorRef.tell(10, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());
        actorRef.tell(20, ActorRef.noSender());

        prematSource.run(system);

    }
}
```

prints:

```
elem is 10
elem is 20
elem is 20
elem is 20
elem is 20
```

So it seems the messages are being sent correctly but the moving average is not being materialized.

Is using `prematSource.run(system);` not the correct way to materialize the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that your `source` is a recipe of sorts for materializing a `Source<Double, ActorRef>` and each materialization ends up being a different source.

In your code, `source.to(Sink.foreach(System.out::println)).run(system)` is one stream with the materialized `actorRef` being only connected to this stream, and

```java
movingAverage.runForeach(n -> {
    if( n > 0){
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}, system);
```

is a completely separate stream with a different materialized `ActorRef` (which ultimately gets thrown away since `runForeach` materializes as a `CompletionStage<Done>`.

When dealing with `Source.actorRef`, it's often a good idea to prematerialize the source before running the stream:

```java
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.japi.Pair
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow

// source is as before
final Pair<ActorRef, Source<Double, NotUsed>> prematPair = source.preMaterialize(system);
final ActorRef actorRef = prematPair.first();
final Source<Double, NotUsed> prematSource = prematPair.second();

Flow<Double, Double, NotUsed> movingAverageFlow =
    Flow.of(Double.class)
        .sliding(2, 2)
        .map(window -> (window.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).sum()) / window.size());

prematSource.via(movingAverageFlow).runForeach(n -> {
    if (n > 0) {
      System.out.println(n);
    }
}, system);
```

(Apologies, my Java is quite rusty)

Comment: My apologies, I was compiling it in my mind... `prematPair` is a `Pair<ActorRef, Source<Double, NotUsed>>` and `prematSource` is a `Source<Double, NotUsed>`.  I basically only write Scala now where I'd typically not include explicit type ascriptions there.

Comment: Likewise with `preMaterialize`: in Scala passing the `system` to materialize a stream is implicit magic :)

Comment: thanks again, please see my latest update. I think I have an issue with how I'm materializing the value?

Comment: Can you try with explicitly sending doubles, e.g. `actorRef.tell(10.0, ActorRef.noSender())`?

Comment: that did the trick! Also, turns out I don't need 'prematSource.run(system);'